# Socket Write() fails in custom class but not in main

Tags: c++, sockets, socketcan

I am working on a simple project using the SocketCAN library to send some messages over CAN. But now I am stuck with a problem that I can not explain by myself... When I am using the socket command `write` within a custom class it fails with invalid argument (errno: 22 - EINVAL). To find my problem I made the whole class public and by using the same functionalities as within my class in my `main` method it works...

Custom Class (not working):

```
void Can::SendFrame(const can_frame &canFrame) const
{
bcm_message request = CreateSingleNonCyclicFrameTransmissionRequest(canFrame);
int result = write(canSocket, &request, sizeof(request));
}
```

Main (working):

```
Can can;
bcm_message = can.CreateSingleNonCyclicFrameTransmissionRequest(canFrame);
int result = write(can.canSocket, &request, sizeof(request));
```

I am using a BCM socket. The socket is connected and working fine (from the main method).

Any idea what might be the problem?

Edit:
If I create the `can_frame` within `SendFrame()` `write()` does not fail.

```
void Can::SendFrame(const can_frame &canFrame) const
{
can_frame testFrame;
testFrame.can_dlc = 1;
testFrame.can_id = 0x321;
testFrame.data[0] = 0xde;
auto request2 = CreateSingleNonCyclicFrameTransmissionRequest(testFrame);
int result2 = write(canSocket, &request2, sizeof(request2));
// as before:
bcm_message request = CreateSingleNonCyclicFrameTransmissionRequest(canFrame);
int result = write(canSocket, &request, sizeof(request));
}
```

Edit2:
There was a difference in the `flags` field of the created requests. In `request2` it is initialized with `0x01` and for `request` with `0x7effb80`... No idea where this comes from... But explicitly setting it to `0x0` solved the problem

Comment: "not working" is not a useful question to post.  What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Where does `canSocket` come from in your class? Are you sure it has the same value as in main?

Comment: @Andrew Henle It fails with an errno saying that an argument is invalid, but I don't see what this might be and I can't spot any difference between the main part and the custom class part...

Comment: @Mat it is a class member and is created before with an initialization. The debugger shows me the same value (0x03) for both the main and the class

Comment: launch it under gdb, set breakpoints at `write` calls and check its arguments. If they are the different, there you go, if not, the problem is in the global state, I would swap the order of `write` calls then just to check.